# Authentication versus Google, Facebook, Twitter with community SDK

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, google-api

we're developing one service to be integrated with various social networks and would like to allow users to be authenticated with their facebook-google-twitter-etc accounts in a simple one-click way.

Most of the huge network providers permit to do it with their proprietary APIs, but for small group of programmers as we are to support all of them is very difficult problem.

**We are searching for some community project which implements most of the proprietary API authentication methods to be included in our small website.**

The developing language is not of huge importance, but it would be great to find one written in PHP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is something you're lookin' for:

https://rpxnow.com/

They also have a free priceplan, and a paid one to access the noticed API's for some cool data.

Comment: Thank you Ronn0. Still proprietary solution, but close to our needs.

Comment: Sorry about that. 

I'm afraid there is (still) no one-click solution for stuff like this, I agree there is a big need for it. Maybe I'll pick it up and work on one. But I'm afraid that's too late for you.

Comment: It is not even about time. Glad to find one who shares the same ideas. It becomes more and more requested now. If you really decide to start opensource project, just let us know. Got some experience about google and facebook APIs.

Comment: I'll let you know when I have time and start it.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've found some more socialauth applications

- The HybridAuth Lib: [http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html)
- The SocialAuth: http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/
- The DotNetOpenAuth: http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/